# How to explicitly write the derivatives of a symbolic function?

Tags: python, symbolic-math, sage, differentiation

I have

```
u = function('u',x)
```

and I'm interested in what happens when powers of some scalar `a` are eigenvalues of the differentiation operator (*i.e.* `D^n u = a^n*u`). For `n=1,2` elementary function examples exist (`De^(a*x) = a*e^(a*x)`, `sin` and `cos` for `a=i` and `n=2`) but for higher powers I need to go abstract.

My question is, how  do you assign derivatives to `u` symbolically? One option is to write a function that differentiates everything normally but sends `u` to `a*u`, but what if I just want `D^3u = a^3*u`?

In other words, if I want every derivative of `u` to just be "the derivative of `u`" (`D[...](u)(x)`) except for the third, which I want to be `a^3*u` for some scalar `a`. How could I implement that?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with the solution you propose in your second paragraph? e. g. in Maxima,

```
D[n](u, x) := if n=3 then a^3*u(x) else diff(u(x),x,n)$
```

gives you what you want, doesn't it?

Maxima lets you assign *first* derivatives symbolically with `gradef`, but I don't know of any way to assign higher-order derivatives that way.